# How to remove any color and let all white-on-transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

[image]

I don't want any blue outline and I expect the "W" to be "opened", without the nested blue parts.

All that is currently blue should be transparent.

I'm new to photoshop, I don't know how to get rid of all blue parts.
Is there any easy way to have a complete white shape on transparent background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the blend modes as I outline below:

1. Your image should be on a layer, if not, double-click on the layer to make it so
2. Double-click on the layer icon to bring the layer style window
3. Change the "Blend If" condition to use Blue channel
4. Move the slider on the "This Layer" slider to around 240
5. Hold the Alt key down and drag the left half of the triangle to the left, to around 220 to get nicely feathered transition

Your image should now be showing only the white W. See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the polygonal lasso or the magic wand tool to erase the blues.

[image]

I would prefer to redraw it again with shapes if that's gonna be a logo but that's a personal opinion.